# Rendering search results in react

Tags: reactjs

In my webapp, I have a Navbar with a searchbar. I want to be able to enter a search query, make an API call, and render the search results in a ResultsPage component. Think just a typical website with a searchbar at the top as an example.

I am having trouble with what approach is best for this. Should I get the query string and call the api in the Navbar component, and then pass the result object in the ResultsPage for displaying the elements? Or should instead take in the search query in the Navbar, and then pass the string to the ResultsPage component where I call the api and display the elements there?

Some guidance would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: use some kind of state management like redux, it will help you when the project rows up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the simpliest example. No loading, and error processing.

```js
const App = () => {
    const [query, setQuery] = React.useState("");
    const [result, setResult] = React.useState("");
    React.useEffect(() => {
        Api.invokeQuery(query)
            .then(result => setResult(result));
    }, [query]);
    return (
        <div>
            <Navbar value={query} onChange={setQuery} />
            <ResultsPage> { result } </ResultsPage>
        </div>
    )
}
```

As a conclusion, you should handle the state at the parent levels of Navbar and ResultPage so that the state can be shared by both components.

Comment: I have an app.js parent that contains the routing. So I define the results page at a certain path, but within the actual resultspage component is where I place my Navbar component since I want it at the top of the page. How would the query from Navbar go to the app.js to call the api? I am new to react so I still am understanding the architecture.

Comment: For a large app, you can use `react-redux` to manage the data. I don't know which router library you choose, The react-router treat a page just like normal component. In react, only parent data can be shared by the children, except you use context. The data manage library such as `redux` usually use `context` to manage data in a large app.

Answer (score 0):

You can call the API with a GET request in the body of the function onChange() in react and then render a carousel combobox just under the searchbar in a SearchForm JSX class  `<input type="text" value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange} />`

Answer (score 0):

You might use Redux to share state between all components which are not inherited as the following.

-- NavBar.js --

```
...
const dispatch = useDispatch();
const onValueChanged = (e) => {
    fetchDataFromAPI(e.target.value)
    .then((res) => {
        dispatch('SEARCH_RESULT_CHANGED', res);
    })
    .catch(e=>{
        console.error(e);
    }
}
```

-- reducer --

```
...
swicth(action.type){
    case 'SEARCH_RESULT_CHANGED':
        return {...state, value: action.value}
...
```

*guess the above reducer was combined as "state.search"*

-- ResultsPage.js --

```
...
const searchResult = useSelector(state=>state.search)
```

*You can use **searchResult.value** in every components.*

Of course, it will be better to use Redux-saga or Thunk than to call **fetchDataFromAPI** function directly in the NavBar component.